# routing/asset pipeline issue - undefined javascript method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, slideshow, asset-pipeline

I'm getting back into Rails (it's been a few years) so I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something simple.  Tho it could also be my lack of understand of how javascript works within Rails.

I think I have my view (in haml) set up correctly. I have added the javascript to a file that I made sure was included in the layout.  (And the css looks right.)  I'm just not getting the javascript function (a slideshow I found online) to connect to the view.  I'm trying to use `%body{ :onload => setUpslideShow() }`

Here's my view:

```
%body{ :onload => setUpSlideShow() }

%script{type: 'text/javascript'}
  if ( ! window.CMFmainmenu ) { CMFmainmenu = {}; }
  var s                   = CMFmainmenu;
  s.user_id               = "#{@user.id.to_s}";
  s.partial_mainmenu_path = "/users/" + s.user_id + "/xx/mainmenu";
  s.add_new_senior        = "#{UsersController::ADD_NEW_SENIOR}"
  s.add_new_senior_path   = "#{new_seniors_settings_path(@locale,@user,@senior)}"

#mainmenu

... (edited out to save space) ...

 #slideshow.greenBorder
        #slides
          = image_tag '/assets/newlook/div_1_img.png', class: 'slide'
          %p
            Everyone loves photo albums.
            Get your user ready to brag, and
            populate and arrange albums by
            event, special people, year or any
            category you can imagine.
            =link_to "Learn how.", ''
          = image_tag '/assets/newlook/div_2_img.png', class: 'slide'
          %p
            If typing is difficult for your
            loved one, remove the frustration
            of a typed response. They can
            respond with a voice message, or
            with auto replies that you set up.
            =link_to "Learn how.", ''
          = image_tag '/assets/newlook/div_3_img.png', class: 'slide'
          %p
            Arms too short? You can specify
            the minimum font size used for
            your user's email.
            =link_to "Learn how.", ''
        #slides-controls
          1
          2
          3
```

Here's my javascript:

```
if (! window.CMFuser) { CMFuser = {}; }

$(function() {

    var s = CMFuser;

... (edited out to save space) ...

       // slideshow

       slidePrefix            = "slide-";
       slideControlPrefix     = "slide-control-";
       slideHighlightClass    = "highlight";
       slidesContainerID      = "slides";
       slidesControlsID       = "slides-controls";

       setUpSlideShow =  function()
       {
... lots of code that doesn't get called so I'm leaving it out to save space ...
```

And here's what I think the relevant line is in the layout: `= javascript_include_tag "lib/modernizr-2.0.6.min", "lib/respond.min","application", "users"` where "users" is the javascript file.  When I comment out the  `%body{ :onload => setUpslideShow() }`, the javascript file appears in the html source.

The full text of the error:

```
NoMethodError in Users#mainmenu

Showing /opt/cmf/app/views/users/mainmenu.html.haml where line #4 raised:

undefined method `setUpSlideShow' for #<#<Class:0x007fe054fa0a28>:0x007fe05594ae20>
Extracted source (around line #4):

2: - # users/mainmenu
3: 
4: %body{ :onload => setUpSlideShow() }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the value for `:onload` be a string?

```
%body{ :onload => 'setUpSlideShow()' }
```

You do want to produce this HTML after all, right?

```
<body onload="setUpSideShow()">
```